# Concatenate pairs of files in a loop

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, merge

I have two lists of files ending with two different extensions and I would like to concatenate them in pairs, in a loop. The file names look like these:

These are the files

```
a.ID, b.ID, c.ID, d.ID     
a.value, b.value, c.value, d.value
```

intuitively I would do:

```
for i in *.ID;  
do  
     for j in *.value;  
do  
     cat $i $j > $i.txt ; done  
done
```

The problem is that I would like to merge `a.ID` with `a.value` and `b.ID` with `b.value` and in this way they are merged randomly. Like `a.value` with `b.ID` etc..

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Samples input `a.ID` (for example):

```
chr1_237301_237601  176 1  
chr1_237601_237901  176 1  
chr1_237901_238201  176 1
```

Samples ending with `a.value` (for example):

```
chr1_1_301      0   0  
chr1_301_601    0   0  
chr1_601_901    0   0  
chr1_901_1201   0   0  
chr1_1201_1501  0   0
```

output:

```
chr1_237301_237601  176 1    
chr1_237601_237901  176 1   
chr1_237901_238201  176 1  
chr1_1_301      0   0    
chr1_301_601    0   0   
chr1_601_901    0   0  
chr1_901_1201   0   0  
chr1_1201_1501  0   0
```

Comment: Show sample input and expected output.

Comment: Just a question - how do you want to merge them ? Line by line ? So line 1 from A.ID get's joined with line 1 from A.value ?

Comment: Hey, I have added the two input and the output. Thanks

Comment: yes they come always in pairs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need two loops.  You need a single loop, through `a`, `b`, `c` etc.  Like this:

```bash
for i in *.ID; do
    b=${i%%.ID}
    cat "$i" "$b".value >"$b".txt
done
```

Comment: Hi, I was trying to understand your code because now am trying to make a similar script. Could you explain a bit? Because basically i have to perform a grep from a list of words with this command:  grep -f A B and I have to do the same as before. The problem is that one file is like in this way: A.not.txt and the other is A.not.txt.duplicated. So the grep in the loop would be: grep -f A.not.tx A.not.tx.duplicated.  Any idea? Or I have to open a new post? Thanks.

Comment: if *.ID is match to "aaa.ID" file then b=${i%%.ID} is extract "aaa" part from $i so next command become cat "aaa.ID" "aaa".value ...

Answer (score 0):

Just because it's possible to do so, here's `find` + `bash` approach.

```
$ ls
a.ID  a.value

$ find -type f -iname "*.ID" -exec bash -c 'base=$(basename -s ".ID" "$@");cat "$@" "$base".value > "$base".merged' sh   "{}" \;

$ ls
a.ID  a.merged  a.value

$ cat a.merged                                                                                                           
chr1_237301_237601  176 1  
chr1_237601_237901  176 1  
chr1_237901_238201  176 1 
chr1_1_301      0   0  
chr1_301_601    0   0  
chr1_601_901    0   0
```