# Loop through 384 pairs and create 384 new concatenated files

Tags: files

I have 384 pairs of files whose names differ by a single character. These represent fastq files from lane 1 and lane 2 of a sequencer. Before I can analyze these, I need to concatenate each pair.

`AA01_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz` and `AA01_S1_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz` all the way through `DH12_S384_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz`. I would like to append L002 to L001 and create 384 new files in sibling directory to be used for analysis.

I tried to do this in R, but packages I've used were out of date. I'm thinking this is trivial in Unix, but my knowledge of unix is quite noobish.

Edit to address questions:
I think these are just gzip files without an index. See output below. I don't think I need any kind of index. Lastly, yes, the only difference between pairs are the L001 vs. L002 and the output names actually should have the name of the L001 ( will pipe output to sibling directory).

```
gzip -cd AA01_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz | head
@D00572:249:HT7WJBCXX:1:1106:8558:1978 1:N:0:AAGACTCTT+AAGGTGTTT
CAGCACCCATGACCGTGCCATTGCTCTCCTTGTCAAAGACACGCAGGCCC
+
DDDDDIIIIIIHIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIHIIIII
@D00572:249:HT7WJBCXX:1:1106:12310:1984 1:N:0:AAGACTCTT+AAGGTGTTT
CCAAAGTCTCAGGACCAACAGGAATTTTGATTGGTGCACCAGAATCCAGT
+
DDDDDHIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIHHIIIIIIIIIIIIIHIIIIIIIIIIIH
@D00572:249:HT7WJBCXX:1:1106:12936:1969 1:N:0:AAGACTCTT+AAGGTGTTT
NAAAGGACCTTGATCTCTTCCTCATATCTGTCTTCCTTCTGCGAGTACTT
```

Comment: Are the files compressed using standard `gzip`, or was `bgzip` from SAMtools used? Is there a corresponding Tabix index that needs to be re-generated? Is the pair always `L001` and `L002` and will the end of the filename always be `_R1_001.fastq.gz`?

Comment: @Kusalananda I addressed in edited question.

Comment: See [Concatenate pairs of files in a loop](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/340109) - and [the dupe it points to](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/347901); yours is a dupe too, except that your files are compressed and you want to create dirs for the resulting files...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files compressed with `gzip` may simply be concatenated together (while still compressed), so there's no need to first uncompress the files. When you uncompress the compressed concatenated file, you'll get the concatenated uncompressed data. This is also true for at least `xz`.

For the concatenation, we may loop over all the `L001` files, create the filename of the corresponding pair, and concatenate the two to a file in a new directory:

```
mkdir output_dir

for name in *_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz; do
    other="${name/_L001/_L002}"
    cat "$name" "$other" >output_dir/"$name"
done
```

Here, `${name/_L001/_L002}` will replace the first occurrence of the string `_L001` with `_L002` in the value of `$name`, creating the corresponding file pair. This other filename is stored in the `$other` variable.

The two files are concatenated with `cat` and the result is written to a new file in the `output_dir` directory. The original files are left in place.

This assumes a shell like `bash` or `ksh93` that understands `${parameter/pattern/string}`.